# lists:keyfind problems

Tags: erlang

I cannot for the life of me get lists:keyfind to work as I expect in Erlang.

I have the following eunit test:

```
should_find_key_test() ->
    NewList = lists:keystore("key", 1, [], {"key", "value"}),
    Value = case lists:keyfind("key", 1, NewList) of
        false ->
            notfound;
        {_key, _value} ->
            _value
    end,
    ?debugVal(Value).
```

Whenever I run this test I get the following error message:

indextests:should_find_key_test (module 'indextests')...*failed*
::error:undef
  in function lists:keyfind/3
    called as keyfind("key",1,[{"key","value"}])
  in call from indextests:should_find_key_test/0

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

Is it saying that lists:keyfind no longer exists?

Comment: Which version of Erlang are you running? `lists:keyfind/3` is quite recent, though I can't remember in which version it was added.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

lists:keyfind/3 was introduced in OTP/R13A.  I suspect you are using an older version..  Prior to R13A you would use lists:serachkey/3.  The same tuple is found, but the returned data is structured a  little different.

```
should_find_key_test() ->
    NewList = lists:keystore("key", 1, [], {"key", "value"}),
    Value = case lists:keysearch("key", 1, NewList) of
        false ->
            notfound;
        {value {_Key, _Value}} ->
            _Value
    end,
    ?debugVal(Value).
```

---

The [release notes](http://www.erlang.org/doc/apps/stdlib/notes.html#id2347497) show the keyfind/3 BIF being added in STDLIB version 1.6.  Check your STDLIB version.

Comment: it was indeed the erlang version.  The installation instructions I read suggested downloading the R12A version.